# Program getting throttled linux c

Tags: c, linux, uart, throttling

i have the following loop that is supposed to run at a little above 40Hz (24ms between each run). It works great for a couple of second to minutes, but then goes down to 20Hz for no apparent (at least not to me) reason.

I have tried running the code on a onion Omega 2 (that runs openwrt) and a ubuntu laptop with the same result. (the code went down to 25Hz on the omega2, and 20Hz on my laptop)

How can i force it to continue to run at the right speed? I have checked with an oscilloscope on the output, and the send_brk and send_dmx functions seem to run perfectly even when the program is throttled, so i don't think they are the problem.

```
double t1 = now();
double t2 = now();
while ( 1 ) {
    // Attempt receive UDP data
    int x = read(sock, &DMX[1], SIZE - 1);
    t2 = now();
    double dt = t2 - t1;
    if(dt < 0.024){
        usleep(500);
        continue;
    }
    t1 = t2;
    printf("Frame in %f %f/sec\n", dt, 1.0/dt);
    if (x < 0) {
        if(errno != EAGAIN){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from socket %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
    }
    send_brk();
    send_dmx();
}
```

the functions called are here:

send_brk() sends a serial break that lasts 88us

```
void send_brk() {
    ioctl(fd, TIOCSBRK);
    double start = now();
    while((now() - start) < 0.000088){
    }
    ioctl(fd, TIOCCBRK);
}
```

send_dmx() writes a byte buffer of lenght 512 to the serial port

```
void send_dmx() {
//  setmode(TX);
    int n = write(fd, DMX, SIZE);
    if(n == -1) {
        if (errno != EAGAIN) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to serial %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (n != SIZE) {
        printf("couldn't write full frame =(\n");
    }
}
```

and now() returns the current time in second as a float.

```
double now() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    double time = tv.tv_sec;
    time = time + (tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0);
    return time;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you're doing this: `while((now() - start) < 0.000088){}`

Comment: Ther is no way to generate a guaranteed timign that way. If you need hard realtime behaviour, you need a realtime OS or RT extensions for your Linux.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why is that the problem? it works fine for up to a couple of minutes

Comment: Linux without extensions is not a realtime OS. And you write it already: "works fine **for up to a couple of minutes**".

Comment: @Olaf as i stated before it works really well for up to a couple of minutes with a consistent FPS of 41, why would it stop after a while?

Comment: @Pownyan The list of problems is long: 1) It causes the process' dynamic priority to drop. 2) It wastes CPU power that other tasks might need. 3) It causes the CPU to needlessly heat up. And so on.

Comment: I don't intend to repeat a third time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz to 2 and 3: the process only takes around 3% cpu when running at full speed, so it is not hogging the whole cpu all the time

Comment: @Olaf i'm sorry if my last comment answering you came out wrong, i wrote it before i saw your second comment. I know linux isn't a real time OS, but games can usually run at a fixed FPS far exceeding 20fps while drawing lots more cpu. I'm just curious why this code can't be made to run as stable

Comment: @Pownyan The issue is not hogging the CPU the whole time. The issue is needlessly hogging the CPU some of the time because that may be the time that other things need it.

Comment: Since you use `usleep()` to sleep for 500 µs, why not use `usleep()` to sleep for 88 µs too?  At the least, that would stop you having a busy loop that may penalize the priority of your program, even if the interval is too small for comfort.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried that at first, but couldn't get it to work satisfactory due to the scheduler, the breaks became to long so i tried this and it "worked" (for a while at least)

Comment: @Pownyan If the breaks are too long, you're sleeping for too long. You need to work with the scheduler, not against it.